# Lua String Manipulation (Find Words Before & After)

Tags: lua

I'm fairly new to this forum. I am having trouble with manipulating the correct string to achieve this.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is receive an input string like this example:

```
str = "Say hello to=Stack overflow, Say goodbye to=other resources"

for question, answer in pairs(string.gmatch(s, "(%w+)=(%w+)")) 
  print(question, answer) 
end
```

I want it to return: question = "Say hello to" and answer = "Stack overflow, question = "Say goodbye to" and so on and so forth. but instead, it picks up the word just before the equal sign and the word just after. I've even tried the * quantifier, and it does the same exact thing.
I've also tried this pattern

```
[%w%s]*=[%w%s]
```

I just want to be able to sort this string into a key-value table where the key is all words before each = and the value is all words after that equal but before the comma.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: The second one you tried is only missing a plus sign at the end to match more than one character.  Other than that, your example does not run (e.g., no DO after FOR, gmatch in pairs, str and s), so if you got it working it wasn't the way you posted here.  This should work: `s = 'Say hello to=Stack overflow, Say goodbye to=other resources'

for question, answer in s:gmatch '([%w%s]+)=([%w%s]+)' do
  print(question, answer)
end`

Comment: Oops, I typed that out in the editor. Although I did have the do in the console I was using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
local str = "Say hello to=Stack overflow, Say goodbye to=other resources"
for question, answer in string.gmatch(str..",", "([^=]+)=([^,]+),%s*") do
  print(question, answer) 
end
```

`"([^=]+)=([^,]+),%s*"` means the following: anything except `=` (`[^=]`) repeated 1 or more times (`+`) followed by `=` and then anything except ',', followed by comma and optional whitespaces (to avoid including them in the next question). I also added comma to the string, so it parses the last pair as well.

To elaborate a bit further per request in the comments: in the expression `[^=]+`, `[=]` designates a set with one allowed character (`=`) and `[^=]` negates that, so it's a set with any character allowed except `=` and `+` allows the set to be repeated 1 or more times.

As @lhf suggested you can use a simpler expression: `(.-)=(.-),%s*`, which means: take all characters until the first `=` (`-` makes matching non-greedy) and then take all characters until the first `,`.

Comment: The pattern `"(.-)=(.-),%s*"` is simpler.

Comment: Thanks Paul, the pattern did indeed work. Although still kinda confused on those anchors you added in the sets. Mind elaborating slightly more?

Comment: Updated the answer to elaborate further.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko Thank you. I understand it better now!